# Make Font Awesome component reusable in React

Tags: reactjs, react-component

Is there a way I can make my component reusable?

I am using react-native-fontawesome npm

here is the original component:

```
export default class Awesome extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight>
                    <Text
                        style={{ margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'left' }}
                    >
                        <FontAwesome>{Icons.chevronLeft}</FontAwesome>//I want to change this line
                        Text
                    </Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    } }
```

I want to pass in my parent component something like:

```
 <Awesome icon="chevronLeft" />
```

and then in my Awesome use

```
 <FontAwesome>{Icons.this.props.icon}</FontAwesome>
```

Obviously this is not the way to do it, but I do not have any good ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way, I can use switch statement

```
<Awesome icon="Back" />
<Awesome icon="Heart" />
<Awesome icon="Share" />
<Awesome icon="More" />
```

and in my Child component:

export default class Awesome extends Component {
    render() {

```
    switch (this.props.icon) {
        case 'Back':
            return <FontAwesome>{Icons.chevronLeft}</FontAwesome>;
        case 'Heart':
            return <FontAwesome>{Icons.heart}</FontAwesome>;
        case 'Share':
            return <FontAwesome>{Icons.share}</FontAwesome>;
        case 'More':
            return <FontAwesome>{Icons.ellipsisH}</FontAwesome>;

        default:
            return <Text>HI</Text>;
    }
}
```

}